# R: Replace column depending on match of two other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dependencies, multiple-columns

Lets assume there are 2 columns of two huge dataframes (different lengths) like:

```
 df1       df2
A  1      C  X
A  1      D  X
B  4      C  X
A  1      F  X
B  4      A  X
B  4      B  X
C  7      B  X
```

Each time there is a match in the 1st columns, X should be replaced with data from column 2 of df1. If the 1st column of df2 contains Elements, which are still not in the first column of df1 (F, D), X should be replaced with 0.

Hence there is a huge dataframe, a loop in a loop would not be useful.

The solution should look like this:

```
 df1       df2
A  1      C  7
A  1      D  0
B  4      C  7
A  1      F  0
B  4      A  1
B  4      B  4
C  7      B  4
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

As there are duplicate rows in 'df1', we can get the `unique` rows

```
df3 <- unique(df1)
```

Then, use `match` to get the idnex

```
i1 <- match(df2$Col1, df3$Col1)
```

and based on the index, assign

```
df2$Col2 <- df3$Col2[i1]
```

If there are no matches, it would be `NA`, which can be changed to 0

```
df2$Col2[is.na(df2$Col2)] <- 0
df2
#  Col1 Col2
#1    C    7
#2    D    0
#3    C    7
#4    F    0
#5    A    1
#6    B    4
#7    B    4
```

---

Or this can be done with `data.table` by `join`ing on the 'Col1' and assigning the 'Col2' (after removing the Col2 from the second data) with the Col2 from 'df3'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, Col2 := NULL][df3, Col2 := Col2, on = .(Col1)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C"), Col2 = c(1, 
1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))

df2 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("C", "D", "C", "F", "A", "B", "B"), Col2 = c("X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```